# How to check if file's content has been modified before submit form by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form to upload a *.docx file, after user select the file, they go back to edit the content of file and save it, then the submit the form without re-select the docx file. It's cause the backend error.

So is there anyway to check if the file's content has been modified before actually submit a form (give user an error notification)?

Comment: The [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) includes the file modified date as a property. You could compare that with the time the page was loaded. That might tell you. I don't see how this produces a _'backend error'_. What is the actual error you are seeing?

Comment: I'm using PHPWord to read the file in back-end. It showed error "No archive file found..." or it just waiting for response then given error code 500 after long time...

Comment: I tried to use console log the lastModified of file, but it doesn't change anything, because the input file is keeping the old one which is selected before...